# MultiException when custom jersey param throws exception

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

NOTE: All code to reproduce this problem is available at https://gist.github.com/SrikanthRao/c9fc35e6fe22a74ab40c

http://localhost:8080/date/bean?date=2014-13-23  (using BeanParam) produces
 "{"code":500,"message":"There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID 48be9aa43bd49547)."}" without adding MultiExceptionMapper to jersey.

If I add MultiExceptionMapper to jersey, the above url results in

"Date is either not in YYYY-MM-DD format or is invalid"

http://localhost:8080/date?date=2014-13-23 (direct @QueryParam parameter) produces
"Date is either not in YYYY-MM-DD format or is invalid"

Couple of questions:

1. Is this the right way to handle input validation in a cleaner way?
2. I expected this to work without needing to add my own MultiExceptionMapper. Doesn't Jersey support custom *Params inside a POJO that is injected as @BeanParam in resource methods?

Here is the stack trace produced when requesting  (without adding MultiExceptionMapper to jersey). Ofcourse removed long traces. Let me know if you need complete stack trace.

```
    ERROR [2015-05-04 18:48:33,366] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 0f23e4de758653d6
    ! javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    ! at io.dropwizard.jersey.params.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:28) ~[dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    ! at com.fun.myapp.LocalDateTimeParam.<init>(LocalDateTimeParam.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    ! at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
...
...
Causing: org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
! 1. javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
! 2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.fun.myapp.PaginationFilters errors were found
! 3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.fun.myapp.PaginationFilters
! 
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:252) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:na]
! at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471) ~[hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:na]
....
....
WARN  [2015-05-04 18:48:33,401] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.params.AbstractParam.<init>(AbstractParam.java:28)
    at com.fun.myapp.LocalDateTimeParam.<init>(LocalDateTimeParam.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
...
...
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.fun.myapp.PaginationFilters errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
...
...
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.fun.myapp.PaginationFilters
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:389)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
```

I've asked this question on dropwizard-user google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/yW-RXSSlspY

Comment: Have you implemented the code corresponding to :  // returns valid Response object here.

Comment: another point. The exception complains about the class com.fun.personal.finance.params.PaginationFilters. Can you check if it has a public constructor?

Comment: Yes I did implement returning correct response. let me update post, so its easier to understand. One more thing is I changed classes here to not copy everything I've. the stacktrace is referring different names. Fixing it. There is a no args constructor.

Comment: the code: return Response.serverError(); didn't compile for me. I had to append a .build(). In addition, @NoArgsConstructor is not a dropwizard annotation. Where did you get it? Btw, when using LocalDateTimeParam as parameter, the error method worked fine for me. The issue seems related to the wrapping in PaginationFilters. Can you provide the code using it so thant I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying that problem is fixed? And you are posting the problem exception prior to fix, and all you want to know is whether the ExceptionMapper is the correct fix?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. AFAIU,your requirement is to get the response from LocalDateTimeParam error method when the input is incorrect. As a start, I used your LocalDateTimeParam as a method parameter. when I pass invalid date format, I get the Response from LocalDateTimeParam. So there is no bug in dropwizard related to calling the error method. Next, I would like test when LocalDateTimeParam is a field of PaginationFilters and the parameter is PaginationFilters. To be in the same conditions then you, I need to see how you injected into resource method using @BeanParam.Can you show that code

Comment: @GuyBouallet Updated post to clarify your questions. Added code to reproduce.

Comment: @peeskillet Updated question to clarify your questions. I fixed it with custom exception mapper.

Comment: @Srikanth Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue. I have a BeanParam where one of the members has a ParamConverter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**

According to dropwizard's core documentation, I see two possible implementations for input validation:

- through validation annotation

> you can add validation annotations to fields of your representation classes and validate them...

This doesn't seem to be suitable for your case. In fact, there is no available annotation for LocalDateTime and creating one leads to parsing the LocalDateTime twice: for validation and for setting bean field.

- Through error handling:

> If you want more control, you can also declare JerseyProviders in your Environment to map Exceptions to certain responses by calling JerseyEnvironment#register(Object) with an implementation of javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper...

To answer your first question, I would say that using an exception mapper is perfectly fine in your case.

**Question 2**
Debugging both isValidDate methods shows that the @BeanParam version uses ClazzCreator.java while the @QueryParam doesn't. This class is responsible for creating the bean class instance. If you check line 226 of [the class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-locator/2.1.79/org/jvnet/hk2/internal/ClazzCreator.java), you will see that it collects multiple exceptions while parsing input with multiple errors. This should allow reporting several errors related to different bean fields, including some subsequent exceptions.

The answer is that Jeysey supports *Params inside a POJO. However, the related exception in encapsulated into a MultiException in the context of @BeanParam.
Consequently, if you are planning to add other fields to PaginationFilters, you should consider reporting multiple errors in your mapped exception message.

Comment: I'm under the impression that constraint validator is executed after Jersey converts QueryParam from request to *Param class. For simplicity I didn't put several arguments inside PaginationFilters. But this has the scope of getting several parameters added to it. If I want to combine multiple errors, I'm at a loss how to do that. If you see MultiExceptionMapper, it finds first error that is of type WebApplicationException and returns its Response. This Response has proper error. For example I can have error payload of certain format. When I have multiple Responses, I'm not sure how to combine.

Comment: This is a different issues. It has been addressed in another response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858450/handling-multiexception-of-jersey. You should be able to adapt it to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1/ in order to validate date, I prefer to parse "dates" myself. It's simple and clean. Here is some working code :

```
package com.rizze.stackoverflow;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;



@Path("/test")
public class TestRessource {


    @GET    
    @Path("is")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public Response isDateValid(@QueryParam("date") String dateString){

        if(dateString == null) 
            return Response.status(400).entity("date is null").build();
        Date thedate =null;
        try {
            thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(dateString);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            return Response.status(400).entity("date malformed").build();
        }
        System.out.println("time:"+thedate.getTime());
        return Response.ok()
                .entity("{\"time\":"+ thedate.getTime() +"}")
                .header("source", "com.rizze")
                .build();
    }
}
```

in this code you will call

```
http://localhost:8080/test/is?date=2014-12-12
```

will return :

```
{"time":1389496320000}
```

take a look at gist : https://gist.github.com/jeorfevre/6e46ae8d9232f7f9d7cc

2/ in order to catch exceptions, a good practice is to catch server level exception with Providers (by registering a provider to your app).
And for App level exception, leverage your exception by yourself using response.status( status of exception) .....

Please take a look at my fork gist, I've added a _ServerError.class and I've registered it in the app :

```
  //register a mapper by rizze
        environment.jersey().register(_ServerError.class);
```

please take a look to official doc that is cristal clear : 
[official jersey representation doc](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html)

Comment: For the sake of simplicity my example shows only one param in PaginationFilters. REST API serving lot of resource methods will have similar input (I mean date being used by several methods, etc), but lot of them. I want to separate the validation as much as possible and not rewrite validation every time. This goal has driven me to use Jersey Params. I think that is the purpose of them. I'm aware of both exception mappers. I'm using existing constraint validators. My concern is seeing MultiException when a custom param is inside @BeanParam pojo.

Comment: This solution results in lots of duplicate code if the LocalDateTimeParam BeanParam is used in many resources.