# Jersey Exception Mapper not handling Exceptions in Resource Constructor

Tags: java, jersey

I have the following Exception Mapper for my jersey-server:

```
@Provider
public class ExceptionResponseMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExceptionResponseMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable e) {
        log.error(e);
        Response response = Response.status(500)
                    .entity(e)
                    .build();

        return response;
    }
}
```

I register this provider with manually with `config.register(ExceptionResponseMapper.class);`

The Exception Mapper works perfectly fine for the exceptions thrown in my REST resource classes, except for exceptions in the constructor.

Eg.

```
@Path("/MyResource")
public class MyResource {

    public MyResource() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

will not invoke the Exception Mapper. How can I handle this case of exceptions?

Comment: Why do you want sideeffects in a constructor anyway? Injected resources should be validated before injection. And here there is no parameter to the constructor, so what is the use-case?

Comment: I encountered this while upgrading Jersey. It worked in 1.19 but fails in 2.x. Why a valid case has now become invalid?

Comment: Created a Jersey issue for this: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/4436

Comment: Maybe `ExceptionMapper<MultiException>` can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858450/handling-multiexception-of-jersey

Answer (score 0):

When your resources are created by either Spring or CDI the Jersey Context is not ready yet is my guess (If you are using a DI framework).

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I already tried "Exception" and "RuntimeException". Both work within a "normal" method but not in the constructor.

Comment: See my edit. Beans are (in Spring) by default singletons and instantiated prior to you registering the exceptionmapper